# Running the scala REPL from gradle?

Tags: scala, gradle

Is there a standard way of invoking the scala REPL from a gradle task? Is there a plugin for this? I have not found one. I could follow this example, but it seems a little dated and I wanted to know if there is a better way:

http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/Reading-keyboard-input-td3073108.html

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Scala plugin bundled with Gradle doesn't have REPL support at this time. However this might change soon as we are currently investing in improving our Scala support. Let us know about your wishes at http://forums.gradle.org.

Comment: Done: http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/running_the_scala_repl_from_gradle. Thanks for the prompt response.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to launch the Scala REPL for a Gradle project: Let Gradle compile and output the classpath, and launch the REPL separately from a shell script.

**build.gradle**

```
project(':repl') {

    def scalaVersion = '2.11.7'

    // Require the scala-compiler jar
    buildscript {
        dependencies {
            classpath "org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:${scalaVersion}"
        }
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }

    // The path of the scala-compiler jar
    def scalaPath = buildscript.configurations.classpath.find {
        it.name == "scala-compiler-${scalaVersion}.jar"
    }

    // The classpath of this project and its dependencies
    def classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath.asPath

    // Prints the classpath needed to launch the REPL
    task printClasspath << {
        println "${scalaPath}:${classpath}"
    }

}
```

**repl.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
gradle :repl:compileScala && \
java -Dscala.usejavacp=true \
     -classpath "$(gradle :repl:printClasspath --quiet)" \
     scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner
```

More details on my [blog post](http://chris-martin.org/2015/gradle-scala-repl/).